Load multiple parquet files in order in pyspark
I have a time series dataset split among multiple parquet files.
files = [
  '0to9999.parquet',
  '10000to19999.parquet',
  '20000to20000.parquet',
  ...
]

spark.read.parquet(*files).show()

Nevertheless, this does not show the rows with timestamp 0 at the top. I understand that the method is concurrent and not sorted.
I could also use orderBy or sort, but the dataset is too big and I don't have enough memory. Furthermore, it should be unnecessary because the data is already sorted! I'd prefer not to have any concurrency.

So do you just wanna display first few records?

Spark is a distributed data processing engine. Order is not guaranteed  like a pandas dataframe. You have to enforce order on it.

I think pola.rs is a better tool for this job
